# Date in right format

Tags: sql, oracle, date

guys. I hava the query,which counts the number of some events per one day.
But it returns date in wrong format.

```
select trunc(action_dt) as action_dt, count(*) as cnt
from stat.jurnal_orders
where action_dt between TO_DATE('17.05.12','DD/MM/YY') AND TO_DATE('12.11.13','DD/MM/YY')
group by trunc(action_dt)
order by action_dt asc
```

In database I have my date in DD.MM.YYYY but I want YYYY/MM/DD
Can somebody help me with that query?

Answer (score 1):

you have two options

First - explicitly set the format you want in the query using `TO_CHAR`

```
select to_char(trunc(action_dt),'yyyy/mm/dd') as action_dt, count(*) as cnt
from stat.jurnal_orders
where action_dt between TO_DATE('17.05.12','DD/MM/YY') AND TO_DATE('12.11.13','DD/MM/YY')
group by to_char(trunc(action_dt),'yyyy/mm/dd')
order by action_dt asc
```

Second, set the `nls_date_format` at session level.

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy/mm/dd';
```

and you query

```
select trunc(action_dt) as action_dt, count(*) as cnt
    from stat.jurnal_orders
    where action_dt between TO_DATE('2012/05/17') AND TO_DATE('2013/12/11')
    group by trunc(action_dt)
    order by action_dt asc
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert dates into a different format you can use the Oracle TO_CHAR function. http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php

For your example, assuming you want to TRUNC the date first, you can use it like so:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(action_dt), 'YYYY/MM/DD') as action_dt
FROM some_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try `TO_CHAR`:

```
select TO_CHAR (sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD') from dual;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), action_dt, 102), '.', '/')
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

EDIT: This is for T-SQL not Oracle. Misread the question.